# Separate key value pair and putting it in another array

Tags: javascript

I have an JSON object like this:

```
{
  "name": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "addresses": {
    "type": [
      "Address"
    ]
  }
}
```

I want an array like this:

```
[{
  "fieldName": "name",
  "fieldType": "string"
 },
 {
  "fieldName": "address",
  "fieldType": "Array"
 }]
```

How do i achieve it?

Comment: What specifically are you having problems with?

Comment: you could parse the string "name" to the key "name" and everything would be easier

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```js
function convertFieldType(fieldType) {
  if (Array.isArray(fieldType)) {
    return "Array";
  }

  return fieldType;
}

function getFieldTypes(definition) {
  return Object.keys(definition).map(function(fieldName) {
    return {
      fieldName: fieldName,
      fieldType: convertFieldType(definition[fieldName].type)
    };
  });
}

var def = {
  "name": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "addresses": {
    "type": [
      "Address"
    ]
  }
};

console.log(getFieldTypes(def));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reorganize your object and that's it.

```
var obj={
  "name": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "addresses": {
    "type": [
      "Address"
    ]
  }
};

var newJSON=[];

for(k in obj){
    var v=obj[k];
    newJSON.push({
        fieldName:k,
        fieldType:Array.isArray(v.type)?"Array":v.type;
    });
}

console.log(newJSON);
```

Comment: i did it the same way but i used if else instead of the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the class type of the "type" property of your object you can try below code

```
 var inputData = {
  "name": {
    "type": "string"
  },
  "addresses": {
    "type": [
      "Address"
    ]
  }
};
var finalArray = [];
for (key in inputData) {
  finalArray.push({ fieldName: key, fieldType: Object.prototype.toString.call(inputData[key].type).slice(8, -1) });
}
console.log(finalArray);
```

You can check below link https://jsfiddle.net/Siddharth_Pandey/4d2u640w/

Comment: I would presume he wants the _value_ of the `type` property if it's a string, or "Array" if it's an array. If I change that first type to `"number"` your code returns `"String"` for the first type.

Comment: His question was not that clear that's why I mentioned in my answer
"If you want the class type of the "type" property of your object you can try below code"

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that `"type": "number"` shouldn't give the result `"string"`.